# Is it possible to run aws eks job from java code?

Tags: kubernetes, aws-lambda, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks

I need to run EKS job hosted on AWS using Lambda (Java code).
Or
Is there any way to trigger EKS on event basis like S3 Put event.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lambda to process event notifications from Amazon Simple Storage Service.
Amazon S3 can send an event to a Lambda function when an object is created or deleted.
You configure notification settings on a bucket, and grant Amazon S3 permission to invoke a function on the function's resource-based permissions policy.

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/aws_lambda/aws_lambda_using_lambda_function_with_amazon_s3.htm) is a step-by-step tutorial.